# Mouse Scroll in ArcGIS different from that of Google Maps?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-maps

On moving the mouse scroll forward, the map Zooms-Out in ArcGIS while it Zooms-in in Google Maps.

Can it be changed to match the Google behavior?

Comment: You can change this functionality in the Customize toolbar, enabling Zoom Out when scrolling forward.

Comment: ArcMap was first! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can change this by going to `Customize -> ArcMap Options` then click on the `General` tab and you'll find mouse wheel settings at the bottom. (Version 10.2+)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the option to do this has been available since at least 10.0.  I suspect the difference arose because two companies developed their software independently.  I prefer the convention ArcGIS uses but then I also drive on the left hand side of the road.

Comment: @PolyGeo I've driven on both sides of the road and I prefer scroll forward to zoom in.  Most programs use this functionality.  So, whenever I have a fresh install of ArcGIS, it's the first thing I change.

Comment: Even I prefer to scroll forward when I have to zoom-in. I'm not sure if it's because I use Google maps quite often compared to ArcGIS

Comment: @PolyGeo You're right, though I left that 10.2+ note in there because I think the way to get to that option has changed since 10.0.